# Как заменить многократное использование  oci_fetch_array

Tags: php

Всем, привет! Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно организовать циклы, вернее, что подставить в условие после того как извлек данные из курсора функцией **oci_fetch_array**, тут понятное дело, что данная функция прокатит только в первом цикле, а вот во втором и т.д. уже не сработает, так как данных уже нет, это если я конечно правильно все понимаю:

```
//  Генерируем ТИП ЦБ
    $result = '<p style="padding-top: 15px;">Тип ЦБ<br><select class="form-control cbType"><option>Все</option>';
    while($data = oci_fetch_array($curs))
    {
        if($data['ITEM_TYPE'] == 'sm_type')
        {
            $result .= '<option>'.iconv('cp1251','utf-8', $data['ITEMS']).'</option>';
        }
    }
    $result .= '</select><br></p>';

//  Генерируем КОД ЦБ
    $result .= '<p style="padding-top: 15px;">Код ЦБ<br><select class="form-control cbType"><option>Все</option>';
    while($data = oci_fetch_array($curs))
    {
        if($data['ITEM_TYPE'] == 'sm_code')
        {
            $result .= '<option>'.iconv('cp1251','utf-8', $data['ITEMS']).'</option>';
        }
    }
    $result .= '</select><br></p>';

echo $result;
```

Comment: так почему-бы не сделать это все в одном цикле ?

Comment: @eicto Как???? ) помогите, прошу! Я же пробегаюсь по всей таблице один раз и генерю html разметку, при каждом новом проходе будет сгенерена новая разметка... ведь так!? Может с начало пробежаться по таблице, и походу распихать все по разным массивам опираюсь на условия которые внутри цикла описаны, а потом уже генерить контент вытягивая данные из массивов???

Comment: ну я написал как. наверное так.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Так почему-бы не сделать это все в одном цикле ?

```
$opts=array();
while($data = oci_fetch_array($curs))
    {
            if (!isset($opts[$data['ITEM_TYPE']])) $opts[$data['ITEM_TYPE']]='';
            $opts[$data['ITEM_TYPE']] .= '<option>'.iconv('cp1251','utf-8', $data['ITEMS']).'</option>';
    }

echo '<p style="padding-top: 15px;">Тип ЦБ<br><select class="form-control cbType"><option>Все</option>'.$opts['sm_type']."</select>".
'<p style="padding-top: 15px;">Код ЦБ<br><select class="form-control cbСode"><option>Все</option>';$opts['sm_code']."</select>"
```

Comment: @eicto ТОЧНО! о_О, спасибо )